# Get total marker count from Google API placesSearch

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In the example fiddle, how can I get the total number of markers displayed on the map? I'm pushing each of the markers into an array like this:

```
markers.push(marker)
```

And attempting to get the total number of markers like this:

```
$('.marker-count span').html(markers.length);
```

Unfortunately, "markers.length" is returning 0 when it should be returning at least 3. 
I have example code here: http://jsfiddle.net/287C7/

How can I display the total number of markers? Is it not possible to add each marker to my array?

I need to know the amount of markers shown so that I can alert the user if there are none.

Thanks,

In case you don't want to view the code on jsfiddle.net, here it is:

```
    var map, places, tmpLatLng, markers = [];

var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(51.5033630,-0.1276250);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5033630,-0.1276250)
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);
    // create the map and reference the div#map-canvas container
    var markerBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);


      // fetch the existing places (ajax) 
      // and put them on the map

        var request = {
          location: pos,
          radius: 48000,  // Max radius
          name: "mc donalds"
        };
        function callback(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
              createMarker(results[i]);
            }
            $('#map-canvas').attr("data-markers",results.length);
            $('.marker-count span').html(markers.length);                  
          } else {
            console.log("Places request failed: "+status);
          }
        } // end callback
        function createMarker(place) {
          var prequest = {
            reference: place.reference
          };
          var tmpLatLng = place.geometry.location;
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: place.geometry.location
          });
          markers.push(marker);
          markerBounds.extend( tmpLatLng );
        } // end createMarker
        service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
```

Comment: Please post the relevant code in your question itself, not just a link to a fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the placesSearch call is asynchronous, when you run your code:

```
$('.marker-count span').html(markers.length);
```

the result hasn't come back from the server yet.  You need to do that in the call back after you update the markers array.

```
        function callback(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
              createMarker(results[i]);
            }
            $('#map-canvas').attr("data-markers",results.length);
            $('.marker-count span').html(markers.length);                  
          } else {
            console.log("Places request failed: "+status);
          }
        } // end callback
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/287C7/1/)