# Google Maps Data Layer - get number of markers (features)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

ORIGINAL QUESTION:
I'm loading geoJSON data into my map using `Data Layer` and I'd like to display the number of markers that get loaded, somewhere next to the map key icon. What's the best way to do this?  Is there a method for simply getting the number of features in the Data layer?

REVISED QUESTION:
I am loading multiple data layers into variables (ie. memberLayer, trailLayer, etc) and I'd like to count how many markers are in the memberLayer. How can I get an accurate count of markers from a data layer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24070293/get-total-marker-count-from-google-api-placessearch

Comment: I don't understand why this was marked as on hold. The question was rather clear. He has markers he loaded as point locations using one of the Data Layer's methods for loading geojson and now he wants to determine their count. Also the link in above comment is something absolutely different from what user is trying to achieve

Comment: @Thinker This would work if I was using a service that allowed for a callback. I don't see that option for loadGeoJson method. Maybe I'm missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `google.maps.Data` class supports `forEach(callback:function(Data.Feature))` function which iterates over every object in the data layer. According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data), the function:

> Repeatedly invokes the given function, passing a feature in the
>   collection to the function on each invocation. The order of iteration
>   through the features is undefined.

So to calculate all the `markers` (provided all the `features` in your `geojson` file are points and `map.data` is your data layer) you can use this code:

```
var total = 0;
map.data.forEach(function(){ total++; });
console.log("In data layer, there's total of " + total + " features.");
```

**EDIT**

If you are using `loadGeoJson(url, options?:Data.GeoJsonOptions, callback?:function(Array<Data.Feature>))` function to load the geoJSON you can leverage the 3rd parameter `callback`, to get the number of features in the layer like this (e.g):

```
loadGeoJson("URL", {}, function(features){ 
     log("loadGeoJson finished, number of features:" + features.length);
});
```

Comment: Tried this but my array is 0.  
    `try {  
        var temp = [];  
        memberLayer.forEach(function (feature) {  
            temp.push[feature];  
        });  
        $("#map-key a[layer='memberLayer']").append("(" + memberTotal+")");  
        log(temp);  
    } catch (err) {  
        log(err);  
    }`  
  
The console log shows:  
'[trails] [Array[0]]0: Array[0]length: 1__proto__: Array[0]'

Sorry for the formatting . . . I couldn't get the code block to work.

Comment: Just saw my error . . . push[] not push()...  still showing empty array

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I'm loading multiple data layers so I am placing each data layer in a variable (ie memberLayer, trailLayer, etc). The foreach function works it just doesn't loop through anything.  
I wonder if I need to have some sort of listener to wait until the json data is loaded before doing the foreach but I cannot find any such listener.

Comment: Depends on the way you are adding the geoJSON to the data layer. If you are using `loadGeoJson(url, options, callback)` function, then you can leverage `callback` parameter, which is a function which get's called after every added feature. If you are using `add` or `addGeoJson`, you can add listener for `addfeature` event on data layer before loading and count number of times it gets called.

Comment: I didn't see in the documentation where you could add a callback to the loadGeoJson method... trying that now.

Comment: I didn't see in the documentation where you could add a callback to the loadGeoJson method... trying that now.  
  
`memberLayer = new google.maps.Data();
    memberTotal = 0;
    memberLayer.loadGeoJson('scripts/php/members_geojson.php', null, function (feature) {
      memberTotal++;
    });
    log("memberTotal", memberTotal);`
  
console.log rendered: ["memberTotal", 0]

Comment: It probably takes some time to call the callback function. Try `{ memberTotal++; console.log(memberTotal); }` inside the callback to see if it even gets called.

Comment: Got it!  It doesn't iterate through the features it returns an ARRAY of features so I just had to get the length of the array. `memberLayer.loadGeoJson('scripts/php/members_geojson.php', null, function (feature) {
      log("loadGeoJson", feature.length);
    });` **Add this as an answer and I'll upvote it. Thanks for your help!**

Comment: You are right, my bad, I missread the docs. I will update the answer.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: After digging into the debugger, I started using: Object.keys(DataLayer.g.i).length